# What is the conventional structure for Python 3 packages?

Tags: python-3.x, module, package, structure, conventions

I am trying to create a Python 3 package. I want to be able to import from the package with the following syntax:

```py
from package.subpackage1 import Object1
from package.subpackage2 import Object2
```

I don't know the optimal way to structure my package and can't find any good information on the following subjects:

- What do I put in the `__init__.py` files?
- Where are the tests placed?
- How do I structure the subpackages?
- What do I put in the `setup.py` file?